# Volunteer Signup - Display quantity/quantity_needed

Tags: civivolunteer

I've been modifying the sign up page to better suit our needs. I've figured out how to add Quantity but how would I go about counting the remaining need?

In other words, I'd like to show the total needed and the remaining needed after someone signs up.

Answer (score 1):

quantity_assigned is the variable.

Comment: is this a comment or an Answer?

Comment: It's the answer but I can't mark it as such for another 18hrs.

Comment: Please expand the answer so it is useful to others. What are you doing with that variable?